# Trying to out the data but doesn't show up in the template

Tags: django

I am trying to pass the data to the template but it doesn't show up

```
<div id="table">
    <table id="table_id">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                 <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for key, value in users.items %}
            <tr>
                 <td>{{ key }}{{ value }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

and this is the view

```
@login_required
    def event_detail(request, pk):
        messages = Chat.objects.filter(room=pk)
        users = Chat.objects.filter(room=pk).values('user__username').distinct()
        event_users = Event.objects.filter(id=pk)
        response_data = {
            'messages': messages,
            'pk': pk,
            'users': users
        }
        return render(request, 'chat/event_detail.html', response_data)
```

My table doesn't show data.

Comment: What you expect in `key` and `value`?

Comment: {'user__username': 'bobo'} {'user__username': 'malika'} I am trying to get the value only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`users` isn't a dict, it's a QuerySet.

```
{% for user_values in users %}
    <tr>
         {% for key, value in user_values.items %}
             <td>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</td>
         {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Edit:

I changed it to support your usage of `.values()`. However, unless you have a great reason to do so, I'd recommend using the ORM, `.select_related('user')` and model instances rather than `.values()`. Simplicity can outweigh performance.

Edit 2:

If you want a list of usernames you can do this:

```
usernames = Chat.objects.filter(room=pk).values_list('user__username', flat=True).distinct()
```

That will be much cleaner and still do what you originally wanted. Just name the variable to indicate it's only the usernames.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's a ValuesQuerySet, which is similar to a list of dicts. Each `user` in that loop is actually a dict, although it has only a single key-value pair.

Comment: I did that initially and received {'user__username': 'bobo'}
{'user__username': 'malika'} I am trying to get the value only

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that. I've updated the answer along with my recommendation.

Comment: And edited again to show you a anoher way to do what you originally wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You will send a queryset in template. You can try this

```
{% for value in users %}
     <tr>
           <td>{{ value.user__username }}</td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```